# How to simplify this summation: $\frac{2\sum_{k=0}^n2^n}{n+1}=2^{n+1}$?

Tags: summation

So I saw an earlier post where they had this equation here.

$\frac{2\sum_{k=0}^n2^n}{n+1}=2^{n+1}$?

However, I do not know how they did this? Am I missing something?

Comment: The sum is $\underbrace{2^n+2^n+\cdots+2^n}_{n+1\text{-terms}}\ $; it simplifies to $(n+1) 2^n$.

Comment: $n$ is arbitrary; there is no $k$ anywhere in the expression, so *everything* can be factored outside of the summation sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the expression is correct $$\frac{2\sum_{k=0}^n2^n}{n+1}=\frac{2\times 2^n}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n1=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}(n+1)=2^{n+1}$$

Comment: I always been slow when it came to summations.

Comment: You are very welcome ! If every single time I have been slow, I was given a cent, I should be a millionaire. So, don't worry. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^n=2^n\cdot (n+1)$ Note, that $2^n$ have no index k.